# how to define and walk through array of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data that look like:

```
 COVUP.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20110304144237.001
 DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100730102440.001
 DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100809104005.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125123615.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125153555.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101126162500.001
```

I need to store it as a variable that is array of array. In ruby I'd write

```
databases = {"COVUP"    =>["20110304144237"], 
             "DBB"      =>["20100730102440", "20100809104005"],
             "DOMINIC1" =>["20101125123615","20101125153555","20101125153555"]  }
```

where DBB will have two elements linked to it as there are two lines with DBB string in it.

1. **DBB**.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.**20100730102440**.001
2. **DBB**.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.**20100809104005**.001

   - How can I define such array and
   - How can I walk through such array?

Comment: can you write an example of how do you want the array to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method:

```
$data = 'COVUP.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20110304144237.001
DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100730102440.001
DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100809104005.001
DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125123615.001
DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125153555.001
DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101126162500.001';

$lines = explode("\n",$data);
foreach($line as $value){
    $line_data = explode(".",$value);
    $array[$line_data[0]][] = $line_data[5];
}

var_dump($array);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array
  'COVUP' => 
    array
      0 => string '20110304144237' (length=14)
  'DBB' => 
    array
      0 => string '20100730102440' (length=14)
      1 => string '20100809104005' (length=14)
  'DOMINIC1' => 
    array
      0 => string '20101125123615' (length=14)
      1 => string '20101125153555' (length=14)
      2 => string '20101126162500' (length=14)
```

**Note that** using php native functions is usually faster than the almighty RegEx, and this code is based on the structure example given.

Comment: I guess I was after this one `$array[$line_data[0]][] = $line_data[5];` thank you

Comment: Hey Paul, i tested the code myself, arrays do not have to be defined before using in PHP, maybe you are confused with some other language.

Comment: it definitely works for me as written above. I like the simplicity of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'COVUP.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20110304144237.001
 DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100730102440.001
 DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100809104005.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125123615.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125153555.001
 DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101126162500.001';

preg_match_all('/^(.*?)\..*\.(\d+?)\.001$/m', $str, $matches);

$array = array();

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $match) {
    $array[trim($matches[1][$index])][] = $matches[2][$index];
}

var_dump($array);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["COVUP"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "20110304144237"
  }
  ["DBB"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "20100730102440"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "20100809104005"
  }
  ["DOMINIC1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "20101125123615"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "20101125153555"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "20101126162500"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have leading whitespace in your array indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "COVUP.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20110304144237.001\n" .
    "DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100730102440.001\n" .
    "DBB.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20100809104005.001\n" .
    "DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125123615.001\n" .
    "DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101125153555.001\n"
    "DOMINIC1.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20101126162500.001";
$dataList = explode("\n", $data);

// create the result array
$result = array();

foreach ($dataList as $d) {
   $columns = explode(".", $d);
   $name = $columns[0];
   $value = $columns[5];

   // add the key name to the top-level array
   if (!in_array($name, $result)) $result[$name] = array();

   // add the value to the array
   $result[$name][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: is your last if block equal to `$array[$line_data[0]][] = $line_data[5];
`?